# What is this deleted scene from the Hateful Eight?

Tags: the-hateful-eight

From the Hateful Eight trailer, I have seen this image which seems to have been deleted from the final film:

[image]

What was this scene about? And how does it fit into the overall story of the film?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a dead body is thrown down the stage car. By two people.
Judging from the fact that there are no horses in front of the car, they might already be in the stable, so this scene is likely to happen just when the stage arrived at Minnie's and Bob took the horses to the stable.

I think I recall a line when John Ruth tell O.B to get the corpse down, but I'm unsure about it. However, I clearly remember that one of the bodies carried by Marquis Warren at the beginning was dressed in red. So this is most likely to be Warren and O.B getting down the bodies

Comment: Interesting but I recall the car was kept outside with the bodies on top of it.

Comment: @DanielV - Hence, this is a "deleted scene".  ;o)

Comment: @jonny  Yeah, you are right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the official published script - there is a scene where Warren offers to pay OB for his help in taking the bounties off the stage coach - we watch it through a window - this scene does not make the final cut - we do see Warren and OB going outside with no explanation in the film - it is visible as the original question notes in some - but not all - of the trailers

Comment: You should provide a link to the script.

Comment: sorry only the leaked first draft is available on line. The official shooting draft endorsed by QT is published by Hachette and is available as a paperback book on Amazon (and I think some other online bookshops) - it is also available as an e-book, but I wanted to read it on the train and tram . There are several scenes lasting a considerable amount of minutes - perhaps 10 minutes more  that do not make it to screen and provide some further insight into the Domergue gang. The scene in which Smithers dead body nearly set the cabin on fire is in both script versions but did not make the release

Comment: also the leaked script is interesting - I actually like the ending far more - Daisy shoots Warren execution-style at point blank :-) and then Mannix shoots her - and is the last man standing - or lying - as he wraps himself up in OB's bear skin and waits on the brass bed to die of his wounds